# How to convert a graph that doesn't satisfy triangle inequality to one that satisfies triangle inequality?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a graph G=(V,E) which doesn't satisfy triangle inequality, I want to solve the TSP question. Then I have an algorithm to solve this question that needs to satisfy triangle inequality.

How to convert a graph that doesn't satisfy triangle inequality to one that satisfies triangle inequality?

Who can give me some suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: On what is the triangle inequality defined? Do the edges have lengths?

Comment: The graph models some situation, if the triangle inequality does not hold, your algorithm is simply not applicable for this situation. There is no way you can meaningfully convert the graph.

Comment: @Henry Thanks your answer!  Your answer means my algorithm, is Christofides Algorithm, is not apply in  a graph not satisfy triangle inequality? If have any other algorithm can solve my question?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks your answer! All edges have weight, According to the triangle inequality, for every three vertices u, v, and x, it should be the case that w(uv) + w(vx) ≥ w(ux).

Comment: I guess this answer your question
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16143/without-triangle-inequality-finding-good-approximate-tours-for-tsp-in-polynomia

Comment: Consider this : if there was a way to transform graph inputs to the Christofides Algorithm so that any graph would be processed, then the algorithm would not have the restriction of needing inputs with the triangle inequality. The first step of the algorithm would be "1) transform the input graph using this function" as a pre-processing step.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a vaguely related graph that obeys the triangle inequality, I would run https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm to produce the all-pairs shortest path distances and then, for each edge, set the length of the edge to be the length of the shortest distance between those two vertices. This obeys the triangle inequality d(a, c) <= d(a, b) + d(b, c), because shortest paths do.